# xsl position() always return "1"

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML and I am planning to get the position of each of the names but it always return "1". With the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
    <collection>
        <item>Paul</item>
        <item>John</item>
        <item>Peter</item>
    </collection>
</main>
```

I used this transformation

```
<xsl:for-each select="main/collection">
   <xsl:variable name="itemName" select="./item" />
   <xsl:variable name="counter" select="position()" />

   <tr> 
      <td><xsl:value-of select ="$counter"/></td> 
      <td><xsl:value-of select ="$itemName"/></td>
   </tr> 
</xsl:for-each>

<!-- desired output is position then name (for brevity purposes): -->
<!-- 1 - Paul  -->
<!-- 2 - John  -->
<!-- 3 - Peter  -->

<!-- but the actual output is like this (for brevity purposes): -->
<!-- 1 - Paul  -->
<!-- 1 - John  -->
<!-- 1 - Peter  -->
```

If I do the above code, the "counter" variable always return 1. I have read in other posts that with XSL, the problem is you cannot change a variable (it's more like a constant that you're setting). So incrementing a counter variable does not work either.

Edit: The more complex XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource ofType="personCollection">
    <personSetList>
        <personSet>
            <descriptorList>
                <person>
                    <personList>
                        <personType>Person</personType>
                    </personList>
                    <personTerm format="plain-text">
                        <personText>Paul</personText>
                    </personTerm>
                </person>
                <person>
                    <personList>
                        <personType>Person</personType>
                    </personList>
                    <personTerm format="plain-text">
                        <personText>John</personText>
                    </personTerm>
                </person>
                <person>
                    <personList>
                        <personType>subject-heading</personType>
                    </personList>
                    <personTerm format="plain-text">
                        <personText>Peter</personText>
                    </personTerm>
                </person>
            </personList>
        </personSet>
    </personSetList>
</resource>
```

And the XSL:

```
  <xsl:template match="<my-match-query>" mode="edges">    
    <xsl:for-each select="descriptorList/person/personTerm/personText">      
      <!-- other declarations -->
      <xsl:variable name="counter" select="position()" />
      
      <xsl:call-template name="templateToProcess">
        <xsl:with-param name="hierarchy" select="$counter" />
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>    
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: The `for-each` selects collections, there is one of them, so it has position 1. Apparently you meant to select `main/collection/item`. I also don't see how you would get three `<tr>` with this code.

Comment: @GSerg You can ignore the <tr>. This is actually a snippet of a larger XML file. I did change the path of the for-each but what bugs me is while I can get the distinct names, wouldn't that follow that the index has changed?

Comment: No, @GSerg is right that your actual output (having nothing to do with `tr` elements) would not be as shown in your question.  As Michael explains in his answer below, `position()` is counting `collection` elements, not `item` elements.

Comment: @kjhughes i think i made an oversimplified version of the xml that I am trying to solve in trying to obfuscate the real code. my sample is really complex like the updated complex xml. I can still get over the names, but the position doesn't change if i use the path of for-each as: desciptorList/person/personTerm/personText

Comment: If you're going to completely change the XML, you'll have to post the corresponding (failing) XSLT as well.  However, I suspect that the principles described by @GSerg and michael.hor257k apply just as much to your actual code as to your original example.  Do you understand the principles behind their guidance?

Comment: @kjhughes indeed. the for-each should point to a path that needs to be traversed and matched with. i have updated the xsl too, if that helps

Comment: Even after a failed iteration due to an *incomplete* [mcve], you still refuse to create a proper ***minimal, complete, verifiable example*** of your problem?  Good luck.

Comment: Voting to close because the problem cannot be reproduced using the provided code. Please show more consideration for the time of the people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `collection` in your input, therefore the instruction `<xsl:for-each select="main/collection">` will execute exactly once. To get the result you indicate you should do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="main/collection/item">
   <xsl:variable name="itemName" select="." />
   <xsl:variable name="counter" select="position()" />

   <tr> 
      <td><xsl:value-of select ="$counter"/></td> 
      <td><xsl:value-of select ="$itemName"/></td>
   </tr> 
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This still returns "1"

Comment: No, it does not: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcy7

Comment: @Patrick, your unexplained (and erroneous) assertion that this code ["still returns 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66538203/xsl-position-always-return-1#comment117627179_66538288) combined with your [denial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66538203/xsl-position-always-return-1#comment117627236_66538203) of [GSerg's correct observation of the results of your original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66538203/xsl-position-always-return-1#comment117626524_66538203) suggest a gap between your actual code and what you've included in your question.